# Настройка видеонаблюдения motion (игнорирование солнечных бликов)

Tags: linux, умный-дом

Добрый день, быть может у кого-то был опыт в настройке ПО [motion](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome). Интересует тонкая настройка для игнорирования солнечных бликов при отслеживании движений.

На данный момент все мои эксперименты с конфигурацией завершились неудачей, motion продолжает засыпать меня сообщениями о движении, хотя это лишь "солнечные зайчики".

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не имеет отношения ни к программированию, ни к администрированию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос действительно не соответствует формату ресурса, но в связи с тем, что тема видеонаблюдения лично мне интересна, хотел бы на него ответить, пока ещё это возможно.

В motion нет детекции объектов как таковых, а детектор движения основан на алгоритме, анализирующем межкадровую разницу. Иными словами, что солнечные зайчики, что деревья, что люди, да что угодно, изменяющееся во времени, будет генерировать это самое движение. Отсюда получается, что единственными существенными инструментами, могущими помочь в отсеве ложных движений, являются указание области интереса на кадре и удаление т.н. ложных пятен на результирующей матрице, воспроизводящей движение.

Первое можно осуществлять через маску, предварительно сохранённую в графический файл, либо параметр `area_detect`.

Второе контролируется параметром `despeckle`, который по сути своей активирует выполнение морфологических операций эрозии и дилатации на результирующей матрице, воспроизводящей пойманное движение. Но эрозия и дилатация могут помочь в отсеве ложных срабатываний только в случае, если размер последних не сильно приближен к размеру объектов интереса. То есть, если солнечные зайчики действительно маленькие по отношению к видимым размерам, например, фигур людей, то данный инструмент будет полезен, поскольку позволяет при должном количестве итераций мелкие объекты свести на нет.